# Affect DOM elements by passing checkbox value attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change attribute values of `div` by checking checkboxes. I'm trying to make some kind of filter and filter out `div` by passing checkbox value to the function. Checkboxes are added dynamically in `div` with id `browse_options`.

```
<div subcategory='1'></div>
<div subcategory='2'></div>
<div subcategory='3'></div>

<input class="filter_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="filter_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input class="filter_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3">
```

My jQuery code, essentially I'm trying to loop through inputs and then `div` but I can't get it to work for few hours now so I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated.

```
$('#browse_options').on("change", ".filter_checkbox", function(){
  $('.filter_checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox){
    if($(checkbox).prop('checked')){
      $('div#results>div.item.filter').each(function (index, card){
        if($(checkbox).attr('value') != $(card).attr('subcategory')){
          $(card).removeAttr('style');
          $(card).css('display','none');
        } else {
          $(card).removeAttr('style');
          $(card).addClass('filter2');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the nice things about jQuery are implicit loops. Most `.each` operations on collections can be done using selectors or filtering. Instead of writing

```
$('.filter_checkbox').each(function (index, checkbox){
            if($(checkbox).prop('checked')){ /* do stuff */ }
});
```

you can write

```
$('.filter_checkobx:checked').each( function(index, checkbox){ /* do stuff */ })
```

so you only work with the checked inputs.

To get the divs with `subcategory` attribute equal to input `value` attribute you can simply use

```
$('div[subcategory=' + checkbox.val() +']');
```

or get them all and filter by attribute value

```
$('div[subcategory]').filter( function(index, category){
    return $(category).attr('subcategory') == checkbox.val();
});
```

I've re-created the code using the above principles (and some more), there's a [**demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wLpS/) and here's a commented version:

```
$('#browse_options').on("change", ".filter_checkbox", function(){
    // get the subcategory divs to use later, 
    var categories = $('div[subcategory]'); 
    // make a list of the values of checked checkboxes.
    var selected_values = $('.filter_checkbox:checked').toArray().map( function( checkbox ){
       return checkbox.value; 
    });

    categories
         // remove style and hide all the divs
        .removeAttr('style')
        .hide()
         // find the divs with subcategory attribute in the list of selected values
        .filter( function( index, cat ){
             return selected_values.indexOf( $(cat).attr('subcategory') ) > -1;
        })
        // now show the divs in filtered collection
        .show();
});
```

Comment: Man, this is the best answer I've ever received on stack. I thank you for your detailed elaboration. If you ever visit Serbia, or if you maybe visit EXIT festival in Novi Sad this summer I must buy you a beer. Best regards